# Kotlin iterate a collection and map a certain value to new map

Tags: kotlin

I have a map of collections . I need to get a list of ids from that..

```
val m1 = mapOf("id" to 1, "name" to "Alice")
val m2 = mapOf("id" to 2, "name" to "Bob")
val m3 = mapOf("id" to 3, "name" to "Tom")
val nameList = listOf(m1, m2, m3)
```

The result shall be `[1, 2, 3]`

Comment: The title says you want a map, but the example result is a list. Which do you want?

Comment: What is the relationship between the `Int` and `String` values of the map? Why do you need to mix them in the same map, meaning you cannot take advantage of generics?

Comment: As Adam indicates, this may not be the most suitable data structure for your situation.  Instead of maps, have you considered creating a `data class` with fields called `id` and `name`?  You could then get all their IDs with just `nameList.map{ it.id }`, and all the types would just work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first, I believe that if you can, you should use classes instead of maps for storing heterogeneous data like this. So instead of your maps, you can  use:

```kotlin
data class Person(val id: Int, val name: String)

val m1 = Person(id = 1, name = "Alice")
val m2 = Person(id = 2, name = "Bob")
val m3 = Person(id = 3, name = "Tom")
val list = listOf(m1, m2, m3)

val idsList = list.map { it.id } // no error handling required, rely on the type system
```

---

Now, if you really want to use maps like that, you have several options.

If you're certain the `id` key will be present and its value will be an `Int`, you can use the following:

```kotlin
nameList.map { it["id"] as Int }
```

This will fail with `NullPointerException` if `id` is not present in one of the maps or with `ClassCastException` if it's not an `Int`.

Normally you should make sure your map matches your contract at creation time, and not when accessing this kind of information.
But if you need to handle errors here for some reason, you can use the following instead:

```kotlin
nameList.map {
    (it.getValue("id") as? Int) ?: error("'id' is not an Int")
}
```

`getValue` fails on absent keys with `NoSuchElementException`, and the `error()` call fails with `IllegalStateException`. You can also use other kinds of exceptions using `throw` or `require()`.

If you want to just ignore the entries that don't have a valid integer `id`, you can use the following:

```kotlin
nameList.mapNotNull { it["id"] as? Int }
```

If you want to ignore the entries that don't have an `id`, but fail on those who have a non-integer id, you can use this:

```kotlin
nameList.mapNotNull { map ->
    map["id"]?.let { id ->
        (id as? Int) ?: error("'id' is not an Int")
    }
}
```

These 2 last examples rely on `mapNotNull`, which filters the elements out if their mapped value is `null`.

Comment: Worth mentioning that this will throw `NullPointerException` if there is no value, and `ClassCastException` if the value is not an `Int`.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip yes, I believe you're right that it should be mentioned. I added a few more versions depending on what's considered an error or not.

Comment: That's quite a difference to the previous two-line answer 

Comment: That's the difference between me answering from my phone and from my computer :D

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you want a list as per the example, not a map as per the title, I would do it like this:

```
val result = nameList.map {
    it.getValue("id").also { id ->
        require(id is Int) { "id must be an Int" }
    } as Int
}
```

This has the advantage of handling the following errors cleanly:

- The `id` key is missing: `NoSuchElementException: Key id is missing in the map`
- The `id` value is not an `Int`: `IllegalArgumentException: id must be an Int`